# How do I fasten NM cable to a concrete wall?

Tags: electrical, concrete

I have a finished basement with some concrete walls, and romex running along the wall (which will be behind drywall). How can I fasten the NM cable to the concrete to support it? It is not running through studs as usual. I tried these which are supposed to work with masonry: https://www.homedepot.com/p/GARDNER-BENDER-1-2-in-White-Plastic-Masonry-Staples-for-UF-Cables-25-Pack-PSM-1550/100157519

However, they mostly chipped away and bounced off the concrete. Is there a strap I can use with a regular concrete screw?

Comment: Drill a hole, use "mounting cable ties".

Comment: What will be supporting the drywall?

Comment: What's going to protect the wiring from accidentally getting pierced (and shorting out, popping a breaker) at some point in the future when you go to hang something on the wall like a picture or a mirror?

Comment: Pictures won't go low to the ground where the wire is, and any wood supports it runs behind at shallow depth will have nail stops.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to using these is that you need a heavy hammer. I've got a 5lb sledge that works pretty well. You've got to hit them pretty hard and hit them square. With some poured in place concrete walls, I've pre drilled holes with a 1/8" mortar bit about half the depth and them hammered it in the rest of the way or drilled to the full depth and shove a few toothpicks in the hole and then hammer in the nail. There are different types of steel strapping you could try but be careful because they can easily cut through the insulation.

Comment: I may try predrilling some and get a bigger hammer, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work (the pre-drilling or heavy hammer). I may need to find something that can just use a concrete screw.